# Assembly location for Razor SDK Tasks was not specified

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core, msbuild

My project fails to build on a build server.
I recently added a new ASP.Net Core (2.2) MVC project with razor pages. The project and the rest of the solution target the .Net Framework 4.7.2.

In Visual Studio on my dev-machine this works fine, but the build server cannot build it. It shows this error.

> C:\Users\tfs-build.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.design\2.2.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.CodeGeneration.targets(161):C:\Users\tfs-build.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.design\2.2.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.CodeGeneration.targets(161,5):
>   Error : Assembly location for Razor SDK Tasks was not specified. The
>   most likely cause is an older incompatible version of
>   Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor, or Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web used by this
>   project. Please target a newer version of the .NET Core SDK.

I made my coworker install the [.Net Core SDK 2.2](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download), since I remembered installing that on the dev-machine to be able to create the project. But this did not help on the buildserver.

What could cause this? Why is the behaviour different from the development environment?

Comment: Add the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor package

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It worked on the build server, after I added this Nuget package:

```
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor
```

Since I added the Net.SDK.Razor package, it builds successfully.

I had also added `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design`, but only `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` is actually needed.

Comment: I tried all combinations, and for me adding only Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor works.

Comment: It definetly works for me with adding Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor nuget package

Comment: Do you have the version?