# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.CodeGeneration.targets(161, 5): Assembly location for Razor SDK Tasks was not specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.CodeGeneration.targets(161, 5): Assembly location for Razor SDK Tasks was not specified.
The most likely cause is an older incompatible version of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor,
or Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web used by this project.
Please target a newer version of the .NET Core SDK.
```

I have the below package reference

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <AssetTargetFallback>$(AssetTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</AssetTargetFallback>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <AssemblyName>LegalRegTech.Web.Public</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.8</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <LangVersion>7.2</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="2.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ValueTuple" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

By adding `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` still not able to resolve the issue. Tried the solution from this [Assembly location for Razor SDK Tasks was not specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55633137/assembly-location-for-razor-sdk-tasks-was-not-specified) but still not able to solve the issue

Comment: Hi @San Jaisy, Your packages all are related to 2.2, but your target framework is 2.1. Suggest you can keep the same. You can create a new .NET Core 2.1 template project , and compare the new one's csproj file with the old one's . Pay attention to `TargetFramework` and related `PackageReference` , check the `Version` variable.

Answer (score 0):

It worked on the build server, after added this Nuget package:

```
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor
```

Since I added the Net.SDK.Razor package, it builds successfully.

I had also added `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design`, but only `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` is actually needed.

[resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55633137/assembly-location-for-razor-sdk-tasks-was-not-specified)